# Linear Transformation $T(A)=A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I got a doubt about a definition, I don't know what is the relation between the composed transformation and the inverse transformation, cause in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-X04WJoTDBc)  at min 3:30 the teacher says that as $T^2 = I$ (which I don't know why, I think that $T^2 = A$, not I) then $T^{-1} = T$. The last is correct, I've calculated the inverse on that vector space and i've got that result, but I don't know if there is any theorem that relate $T^2$ with the inverse. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $T^2(A)=A$ is not the same as $T^2=A$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If $T^2=I$, then $TT=I$. Since $AB=I\implies A^{-1}=B$, it follows that $T^{-1}=T$. There's no need to find $T^{-1}$ explicitly.

Comment: What has $T(A) = A^T$ got to do with anything?

Comment: @copper.hat From watching a bit of the video I gathered that $T$ is a linear transformation on a space of matrices, namely the one defined by $T(A)=A^T$.

Comment: @GitGud: I think I understand what the confusion is. If $T(A) = A^T$, then $T(T(A)) = A$. So, we write $T^2 =I$, where $T^2$ means $T$ composed with itself, and $I$ is the identity mapping on the space of matrices, that is $I(A) = A$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes.${{}}$

Comment: Michelle, you need to distinguish between $I$ the identity matrix and $I$ the identity mapping on the space of matrices. $T$ is a linear operator on the space of matrices, it is not a matrix.

Comment: Thanks copper! that was my doubt. Now it's very clear for me. I thought the teacher was saying the matrix I2x2, and that was confusing me, 'cause I obtained from the operation the same matrix A.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is the transformation that maps $A$ to its transpose $A^t$.

If we apply $T$ another time, the transpose $A^t$ is mapped back to the original $A$.

In other words, we have indeed that $T^2$ is the identity transformation ($I$ or $\ id$) and consequently that $T^{-1}=T$.